# Как добавить trigger в SchedulerFactoryBean после инициализации?

Tags: java, spring

Использую spring 3.2, есть бин планировщика в файле applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="oneTrigger"/>
                <ref bean="twoTrigger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

есть файл schedulers.xml, где прописаны бины задач для планировщика. 
Необходимо добавить в triggers бина scheduler триггеры из этих задач, не изменяя файл applicationContext.xml, либо программно, либо в файле schedulers.xml.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через BeanFactoryPostProcessor:

```
public class SchedulerBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor
{
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException
    {
        StdScheduler scBean = (StdScheduler) factory.getBean("scheduler");
        JobDetailImpl myNewJob = (JobDetailImpl) factory.getBean("myNewJob");
        CronTriggerImpl myNewTrigger = (CronTriggerImpl) factory.getBean("myNewTrigger");

        try
        {
            Trigger trigger = scBean.getTrigger(myNewTrigger.getKey());
            if (trigger == null)
                scBean.scheduleJob(myNewJob, myNewTrigger);
        }
        catch (SchedulerException e)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Стоит заметить, что проверка на наличие триггера нужна в том случае, если триггеры и джобы являются персистентными объектам, если все работает в рантайме, каждый раз поднимая новые задачи при запуске проекта, это не обязательно.

Также у StdScheduler есть параметр, позволяющий перезаписывать триггеры во время их инициализации.

P.S.
SchedulerBeanFactoryPostProcessor, естественно, нужно прописать как отдельный бин в файле schedulers.xml, где прописаны бины myNewJob и myNewTrigger.